# Issue with header and footer of PDF in Spire PDF library

Tags: c#, pdf

I am using Spire PDF as a package to convert HTML to PDF. It works fine for watermark while creating and converting from HTML to PDF. I had a thought to add HTML header to every new page while creating the same.

But i couldn't find any solution or way out to solve the problem. I am attaching a code which i am using but getting an error.

I tried to convert the HTML header to add to the new page but somehow didn't get the successful answer.

```
PdfTilingBrush brush = new PdfTilingBrush(new SizeF(page.Canvas.ClientSize.Width / 2, page.Canvas.ClientSize.Height / 3));
PdfFont font = new PdfFont(PdfFontFamily.Helvetica, 5);
PdfHTMLTextElement richTextElement = new PdfHTMLTextElement(header, font, brush);
richTextElement.TextAlign = TextAlign.Left;
PdfMetafileLayoutFormat format = new PdfMetafileLayoutFormat();
format.Layout = PdfLayoutType.Paginate;
format.Break = PdfLayoutBreakType.FitPage;
richTextElement.Draw(page, new RectangleF(0, 20, page.ActualSize.Width, page.ActualSize.Height), format); // Null Reference exception
```

The actual and expected result was to print header from text to every new page when it's getting started.